# OpenCV outdoor tracking tips

Tags: c++, opencv, openframeworks

I'm currently working on an application that tracks movement on a bridge and could use a few tips to make the tracking more robust. The tracking is done over a long period of time during the day, so tips on how best deal with this are handy.

Currently I'm doing basic frame differencing and blob tracking using OpenCV and OpenFrameworks. Unfortunately in this state, the question is quite open ended: I'm trying to get advice on stable tracking in outdoor conditions:

1. how to handle light changes
2. how to ignore shadows (tracking dark blobs can trigger shadows to be tracked as well)
3. how to isolate people (I've looked into OpenCv's HOGDescriptor but it's a bit much for my setup, I can deal with simpler/less exact data)

Also I'm thinking of improving stability by applying a few filters like blur and high pass on the images. Any other tricks/tips I could use ?

Comment: I don't know about shadows and isolating people but if your lighting changes tend to be distributed and not local you could try to normalize the intensity of the entire frame.  Divide each pixel by the mean intensity.  That should give you some resilience to lighting changes from the sun.

Comment: could you elaborate more for which purpose you want to track? (e.g. counter vehicles, or measure speed?)

Comment: @Hammer That sounds handy. Just to make sure I've understood your suggestion: I should get the average 'luminance'/brightness from the grayscale image and divide each pixel by that value ? If so, sounds easy to test, will give it a shot

Comment: @chaiy It's a pedestrian bridge, luckily gray coloured which makes the people stand out I think. Ideally I would track on which area on the bridge each person is, but currently as mentioned am taking a basic blob/contour based approach.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Yes that is exactly what I mean.  I was assuming you would be working in greyscale but your above comment implies colour processing.  I have not done much colour image processing before so take this with a grain of salt, but you might try normalizing each colour individually.  That might give you resilience to changes in colour based on lighting (ex. sunrise,sunset).  I have never tried it but it seems like it could work...  Normalizing luminance has served me well for greyscale image processing.